# Modifying multiplying calculation to use delta time

Tags: math, multiplication, exponential

```
function(deltaTime) {
  x = x * FACTOR; // FACTOR = 0.9
}
```

This function is called in a game loop. First assume that it's running at a constant 30 FPS, so `deltaTime` is always 1/30.

Now the game is changed so `deltaTime` isn't always 1/30 but becomes variable. How can I incorporate `deltaTime` in the calculation of `x` to keep the "effect per second" the same?

---

And what about

```
function(deltaTime) {
  x += (target - x) * FACTOR; // FACTOR = 0.2
}
```

Comment: What programming language, environment, etc ?

Comment: For the second problem you use a variable  delta = target - x. Then the update function becomes delta = delta * (1 - FACTOR), which you already know to solve. Given delta you can always get x = target - delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = x * Math.pow(0.9, deltaTime*30)
```

**Edit**

For your new update:

```
x = (x-target) * Math.pow(1-FACTOR, deltaTime*30) + target;
```

To show how I got there:

Let x0 be the initial value, and xn be the value after n/30 seconds. Also let T=target, F=factor. Then:

```
x1 = x0 + (T-x0)F = (1-F)x0 + TF
x2 = (1-F)x1 + TF = (1-F)^2 * x0 + (1-F)TF + TF
```

Continuing with x3,x4,... will show:

```
xn = (1-F)^n * x0 + TF * (1 + (1-F) + (1-F)^2 + ... + (1-F)^(n-1))
```

Now substituting the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence will give the result above. This really only proves the result for integer `n`, but it should work for all values.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I've expanded the question with a more difficult problem.

Comment: That also works, thanks again. This one is harder to understand though :p

Answer (score 0):

`x = x * powf(0.9, deltaTime / (1.0f / 30.0f))`